# Receive Mail if matlab is in debugging mode

Tags: matlab, debugging, timer, dbstop

I'd like to receive an email when Matlab is in debugging mode, so I tried the following:

```
timerTic=4; % how often the timer checks

timerHandle = timer();
timerHandle.startDelay = timerTic;
timerHandle.Period = timerTic;
timerHandle.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
timerHandle.TasksToExecute = inf;
timerHandle.TimerFcn = @CheckDebugMode;


j=0;
while t==0
    j=j+1;
end
```

where the funcion is:

```
function CheckDebugMode( ~ )
% Check if Matlab is in Debug mode
if feature('IsDebugMode')
    sendSSLmail('mymail@mycountry','Matlab is in debug mode','Matlab is in debug mode')
end
```

t doesn't exist so that an error occurs and Matlab enters in debug mode (dbstop if error is active).
feature('IsDebugMode') is equal to 1, but I receive no mail.

It's the first time I work with objects in Matlab, so I'm pretty sure the code is in someway wrong.
Maybe someone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you start your timer?

```
start(timerHandle)
```

**edit**  I haven't tested this but I suspect you have problems with your function handle and the function itself.  The timer passes arguments to your function, so you need to accept then in your code:

```
function CheckDebugMode( varargin )
```

or stop then from being passed:

```
timerHandle.TimerFcn = @(~,~)CheckDebugMode
```

Comment: Actually not!
I started it but then I receive the following error:
Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-7' 
Too many input arguments.

timerTic=4; % how often the timer checks

timerHandle = timer();
timerHandle.startDelay = timerTic;
timerHandle.Period = timerTic;
timerHandle.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
timerHandle.TasksToExecute = inf;
timerHandle.TimerFcn = @CheckDebugMode;

start(timerHandle)

j=0;
while t==0
    j=j+1;
end

Comment: I just added the varargin in the funtion. Thanks a lot for your help, now it works!